# PageController overlays other controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

How it is possible to show other controllers on top of the Page Controller?
I have tried both programmatically adding and manually using interface builder but in both situation Page Controller appears on top

[image: page controller]

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton appearance];
    [button setTitle:@"ADD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your page controller added to the navigation controller's view? You probably only want to add it to the related view controller's view.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I have moved the codes to the views (appropriate views) yet Page Controller appears on top of other controllers.